# Orange line on sublinetext how do I fix it

Tags: sublimetext3

[image]

There is this orange line when I mess up on my project and it also annoys me on subline REPL

Comment: Do you miss a ":" there? And please "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. ", check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Shaw you kind of *need* an image of syntax highlighting issues...

Comment: there is some issue in your code so that's my it is showing red line. i think the error is in the print  line

Comment: @AftabAmin the print line is fine. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are either missing a closing double quote `"` in the line:

```py
else:jska(s"sa)
```

or the quote is unintentional. Either way, it's just a typo, which the syntax highlighter can often recognize and point out to you. It's a feature, not a bug.

Just as a point of code style: it is recommended by [PEP 8 -- The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that `else:` statements be on their own line, and any code that is to be executed in the `else` block be on the next line, indented by 4 spaces.